# If $a_n$ converges to $a$, can we say $a_n^c$ converges to $a^c$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm doing a lot of practice problems with sequences, and I've noticed a number of problems ask about the convergence of the sequence raised to a positive power. It seems like in all the examples that I've tried, if $a_n$ converges to $a$, then $a_n^c$ converges to $a^c$, where $c$ is some positive real number. Is this always true?

I want to say yes, since we can define a new sequence $b_n$ as the product of $a_n$ and use the Algebraic Limit Theorem, but I'm wondering if there are any special cases I'm failing to consider.

Comment: There is a problem with definition of $a_n^{c}$ when $a_n <0$.

Comment: I understand! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement does not hold.
For example, take $a_n = -1/n$ and $c=0.5$. $c$ is a positive real number, $a_n$ convergese to $0$, but $a_n^c$ is not defined for all $n$, so the sequence does not converges.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you!